# Installing drivers from NVIDIA website for gtx 760?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xserver

I recently bought a gtx 760, but upon using the drivers from the additional drivers menu doesn't gain any fps increase over my old gt530 card.
I decided to go to the nvidia website and I downloaded the latest version of the driver: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20.run is the file i got.
But when i open the terminal and sh the file it tells me that i still have an X server running, and that I can't install the driver. Is there any way i can stop X server or load up ubuntu without X server loading too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into Virtual console <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.And run the below command to stop the X server,

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: And after that i just sh the nvidia file?

Comment: yes,move to the directory and then execute the .run file.